Limiting difference of function and sum of its derivative
I was reading about the Euler-Mascheroni Constant, and it made sense to me because $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac 1 k$ is like a bad Riemann Sum, and the derivative of $\ln x$ is $\frac 1 x$. My question is about when else this happens. At first, I noticed how it kind of looks like $\ln x$ flattens out a little, and thought about how its derivative $\frac 1 x$ goes to 0. My friend suggested that it may be related when a function's derivative converges to any real number at all. So, I am asking if it is known the conditions for $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\sum_{k=1}^n f'(k) - f(n)\right)$$ to converge to some $L \in \mathbb R$.

Not an Answer, but you might read about the Euler-Maclaurin summation formula.  As usually stated, it relates the summation of a function with its integral, but can be massaged to relate the summation of a function's derivative with its value.
